# Dropwizard Forms MULTIPART - Resource throwing errors on start up

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jersey, multipartform-data, dropwizard

I'm trying to get a multipart file upload working inside of drop wizard 0.7.1.  Per an example I saw I added the:

```
'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-forms:0.7.1',
```

To my gradle file.  Then I create the following resource:

```
    import com.path.to.service;
import com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.*;

@Path("/api/v1/files")
@Api("/api/v1/files")
public class FileUploadResource {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadResource.class);
    private final MyService myService;

    public FileUploadResource(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/upload" )
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws MessageException, IOException {

        return myService.process(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail);
    }
}
```

I added the resource to jersey in the main application like the rest of my resources:

```
MyService myService = new MyService();    
environment.jersey().register(new FileUploadResource(myService));
```

When I launch the application from IntelliJ I have no problems...I can upload files to it all day with zero errors or problems.  However when I build it and start it from the command line I runtime errors on startup.  I've read a bit that I might have to register the resource differently by class but I don't get why it works via my IDE in that case.  Also it doesn't seem like theirs tons of support in drop wizard 0.7.x for 'forms' module.  Seems like I'm missing something basic.  Here is the error:

```
ERROR [2015-04-23 21:32:01,409] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public int com.path.to.dropwizard.resources.FileUploadResource.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.io.IOException at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public int com.path.to.dropwizard.resources.FileUploadResource.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.io.IOException at parameter at index 1
Exception in thread "main" javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-2c74ba35@9951d4d9==com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer,1,false
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:812)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
        at com.path.to.dropwizard.application.FileRegistrationService.main(FileRegistrationService.java:50)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540)
        ... 36 more
WARN  [2015-04-23 21:32:01,412] /: unavailable
! com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:812) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:131) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:233) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.path.to.dropwizard.application.FileRegistrationService.main(FileRegistrationService.java:50) [cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
WARN  [2015-04-23 21:32:01,414] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@7d32391c{/,null,STARTING}: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-2c74ba35@9951d4d9==com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer,1,false
! com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540) ~[cdi-file-registration-service-dropwizard-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
! ... 36 common frames omitted
! Causing: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-2c74ba35@9951d4d9==com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer,1,false
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with gradle plugin shadow, switching to a different packing tool (which uses a different class loader) fixed my problem instantly.